# How to reload the lowest iframe's parent only

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a page that is already in an iframe that has another page with an iframe within it called "framedets", which allows the user to perform some processing within this iframe.

Within this lowest iframe though, when the user presses a "process" button, I  want to reload the lowest iframe's parent only and not the top most iframe.

I tried `window.top.location.reload(true);` but it went right to the topmost iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `window.parent` not `window.top`

Comment: thanks david. I ended up using just parent.location.reload(true). appreciate you replying back.